# Horizontal autoscroll to loop - currently not possible

Tags: jquery, infinite-loop, fullpage.js

I am using fullPage.js JQuery plugin in my code so I can do horizontal scrolling on full screen divs as follows: - [jsfiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/6SQhb/237/)

```
var slideTimeout;

$('#fullpage').fullpage({

    verticalCentered: false, 
    navigation: false,
    slidesNavigation: false,
    controlArrows: false,

    autoScrolling: true,
    loopHorizontal: true,
    continuousVertical: true,

    afterRender: function () {
        //on page load, start the slideshow
         slideTimeout = setInterval(function () {
                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
            }, 1000);
    }

});
```

The only problem is that after it gets to the last div it scrolls backs to the first one and I'd like to be able to do it in a way that it would go back to the first one as in an infinite loop (continuously) - [example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/continuous.html)

How can I achieve that as there is no "continuousHorizontal: true" option?
I searched here and Google but I could not find anything to achieve what I need.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

There's [an open issue](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/124) in fullpage.js forum at github.

Fullpage.js doesn't currently provide a way to do it. But in case you really need it you can ask for a customization as detailed in one of the answers:

> I customized the plugin to someone requesting a customization like a year ago. Feel free to do the same.

## Update

---

This is now possible through the fullpage.js extension [Scroll Horizontally](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/continuousHorizontal.html).

Comment: Thanks Alvaro. That was exactly what I did but because I am not sure when this could be complete is there any other thing I could do to achieve the same? I think the elements would need to be cloned after the last one is shown as if they were part of the sequence and the former elements deleted after that but I was not able to put that in place.